# Using UTM parameters with current queryparams

Tags: google-analytics

I have a page which gets some queryparameters from another page. Just like this:

```
https://sampleurl.com?foo=bar&tomato=yes
```

I am trying to use google analytics through UTM parameters. And I append these parameters to the link as this:

```
https://sampleurl.com?foo=bar&tomato=yes&utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=post
```

My analytics team says that these don't work and UTM parameters should be positioned right after the base url like this:

```
https://sampleurl.com?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=post&foo=bar&tomato=yes
```

I mean these are query parameters, positions of these should be irrelevant but I couldn't find any information about the subject saying that the parameter positions are relevant or irrelevant.

Are they relevant for Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a best practice but **it is not relevant**.

Here is a test that I carried out:

```
https://www.my-website.com/?utm_source=test1&utm_medium=test1&param1=1&param2=2

https://www.my-website.com/?param1=1&param2=2&utm_source=test2&utm_medium=test2
```

The result in Google Analytics:

[image]